# "warning: adding embedded git repository" when adding a new create-react-app folder

Tags: git

I just want to simply `git add` my React project to my class Gitlab, but I get a warning:

```
saying:
warning: adding embedded git repository: frontend-Projekt
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> frontend-Projekt
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached frontend-Projekt
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

I don't understand what I did wrong. Can someone help me? Or maybe tell me how to restart git bash so it would work normally again, because I tried reinstalling it and the warning still occurs.

Comment: Did you type `git init`? Or maybe you copied a `.git` folder into another repo?

Comment: i typed git add frontend-Projekt

Comment: `frontend-Projekt` probably has a `.git` folder inside it

Comment: `$ git add frontend-Projekt
warning: adding embedded git repository: frontend-Projekt
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> frontend-Projekt
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached frontend-Projekt
hint:

`

Comment: well it did somehow

Comment: may you share `git status` output?

Comment: `On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   frontend-Projekt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   frontend-Projekt (modified content, untracked content)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
`

Comment: `On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   frontend-Projekt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   frontend-Projekt (modified content, untracked content)

Untracked files:

to long to put in here
`

Comment: What is the repo you are currently in?

Comment: Well, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I tried to creating a new one by git-clone, but still get same warning

Comment: You're trying to use `git add`. This can only be done inside a repo. Which repo is that? `frontend-Projekt` is a repo, which you're trying to add to another.

Comment: How is frontend-Projekt a repo? It is just a folder which i created by npx creater react app

Comment: The error says so `warning: adding embedded git repository`. Try using `npx create-react-app --skip-git` next time.

Comment: may this be because of package-lock.json file?

Comment: No it's because there is a git repo inside another, hence the warning. `npx create-react-app` creates a git repo by default.

Answer (score 3):

You were already in a Git repo when you ran `npx create-react-app …`. This creates a new React app in a new Git repo.

Now you have a Git repo in a Git repo — not what you want.

1. `git reset` the `.git` folder in the React app’s folder to undo the `git add`.
2. Delete the `.git` folder from the React app folder.

Also see [Why is a .git folder automatically being created when creating a react app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54915091/1549818)

Answer (score 1):

Simply delete the .git folder .
Then go to root directory and open command prompt.
type `git add -A` and hit enter.
then `git commit -m "removedembeddedgitfolder"` and hit enter.